# On Qt Creator project based on CMAKE, how to point to VCPKG?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator, vcpkg

On (macOS silicon) Qt Creator project based on QMAKE, I had to add the following in order to make it find VCPKG:

```
QMAKE_APPLE_DEVICE_ARCHS = arm64

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
     MODE = debug
     d = d
} else {

}

INCLUDEPATH += $$(VCPKG)/include
     LIBS += -L$$(VCPKG)/$${MODE}/lib
     LIBS += -lfmt$${d}
```

Considering `export VCPKG=~/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx`.

What about CMAKE? I created a C++ project based on it and looks like the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(untitled1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(untitled1 main.cpp)

install(TARGETS untitled1
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

The [vcpkg instructions](https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html) are for `In order to use vcpkg with CMake outside of an IDE`:

```
cmake -B [build directory] -S . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=[path to vcpkg]/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

How to use vcpkg with CMake inside of an IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as the instruction said, you should not change your CMake files at all and pass this in the command line:

```
cmake -B build -S . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

This assume the environment variable `VCPKG_ROOT` is defined to point to the vcpkg installation.

You can add the toolchain command line argument inside a [`CMakePresets.json`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) file.

Then, to ensure that vcpkg installs what you need, I would also create a manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "version-string": "0.1.0",
    "dependencies": [
        "fmt"
        // or any other dependencies
    ]
}
```

Then, your CMake file should simply find those packages:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(untitled1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(untitled1 main.cpp)

install(TARGETS untitled1
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})

find_package(fmt REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(untitled1 PUBLIC fmt::fmt)
```

vcpkg will actually output usage examples when installing the packages.

Here's an example of a preset file that setup the vcpkg toolchain:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
        "major": 3,
        "minor": 22,
        "patch": 0
    },
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "cmake-pedantic",
            "hidden": true,
            "warnings": {
                "dev": false,
                "deprecated": true,
                "uninitialized": true,
                "unusedCli": true,
                "systemVars": false
            },
            "errors": {
                "dev": false,
                "deprecated": true
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "generator-ninja",
            "hidden": true,
            "generator": "Ninja Multi-Config",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "$env{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
                "CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX": "d",
                "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM": "ninja"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "dev",
            "displayName": "Development",
            "description": "Development preset",
            "inherits": ["generator-ninja"]
        }
    ],
    "buildPresets": [
        {
            "name": "dev-debug",
            "displayName": "Debug",
            "description": "Build with debug informations",
            "configuration": "Debug",
            "configurePreset": "dev"
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-relwithdebinfo",
            "displayName": "RelWithDebInfo",
            "description": "Build with debug informations and optimizations enabled",
            "configuration": "RelWithDebInfo",
            "configurePreset": "dev"
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-release",
            "displayName": "Release",
            "description": "Build with optimizations enabled",
            "configuration": "Release",
            "configurePreset": "dev"
        }
    ],
    "testPresets": [
        {
            "name": "base-test",
            "hidden": true,
            "output": {
                "outputOnFailure": true
            },
            "execution": {
                "noTestsAction": "error",
                "stopOnFailure": true
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-debug",
            "displayName": "Debug",
            "configuration": "Debug",
            "configurePreset": "dev",
            "inherits": "base-test"
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-relwithdebinfo",
            "displayName": "RelWithDebInfo",
            "configuration": "RelWithDebInfo",
            "configurePreset": "dev",
            "inherits": "base-test"
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-release",
            "displayName": "Release",
            "configuration": "Release",
            "configurePreset": "dev",
            "inherits": "base-test"
        }
    ]
}
```

With the presence of the preset file, you have to use this command line instead:

```
# from the source directory
cmake --preset dev
cmake --build --preset dev-debug
```

Refer to the [`cmake-presets` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html)

---

**Not recommended**

You can also set the toolchain file in your CMake file. However, it is ill-advise to do so. It will create problems in the long run. You should make your build specification independent of your toolchain files.

Toolchain files are useful when building the app on multiple platforms and multiple compilers. Hardcoding it is chasing problems.

Here's how to do it:

```
# This will make issues in the future
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "$ENV{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
```

Do that before any call to `project`.

Comment: It seems `VCPKG_ROOT` is not defined here. Should it be manually defined or is it supposed to be defined during VCPKG installation?

Comment: I think yes, it makes using vcpkg more practical in my experience

Comment: @KcFnMi note that when you change the toolchain file, you must delete the build directory as the toolchain file cannot be changed once the cache is generated.

Comment: On QtCreator Build Steps I see `cmake --build /Users/user/QtProjects/untitled1/_x64d --target all`. Seems it should be modified to `cmake -B build -S . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake`. However the fact this is not on project file seems like a disadvantage compared to qmake. Can I set that in an environment variable instead?

Comment: @KcFnMi it should be passed from the preset file. The toolchain is not part of the build specification since technically you may want a different toolchain for each kind of build. It also makes your build specifications totally independent of vcpkg. If you desire you can set the toolchain file in your `CMakeLists.txt` file right before `project()` but I would advise using preset files instead.

Comment: How could it  be passed from the preset file? And how to set the toolchain file in the CMakeLists.txt file right before project()? Appreciate if you could add those to the answer.

Comment: @KcFnMi I added an example of the preset file and also linked to the documentation.

Comment: I'm trying to decide if I should use presets file. It seems the whole thing get more complex by using them.

Comment: @KcFnMi Toolchain is just like an actual IDE configuration. You set command line argument, generators, and how to run your test, select between debug, release and all of that. It takes complexity away from how to run CMake and put all the config in a file. I also added example on how to set a variable such as the toolchain file, but know that this is very ill-advise.